# при импорте компонента возникла ошибка

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

при импорте компонента возникает такая ошибка(см.скрин) в чем может быть дело?

```
import Header from './components/Нeader'

export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <h1>Hello React</h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export function Header() {
    return(
        <header>
            <h3>Result University</h3>
            <span>Тут будет время</span>
        </header>
    )
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не стоит путать обычный `export` и `export default`.

В приведённом коде вы экспортируете компонент следующим образом:

```js
export function Header() {}
```

Импортировать его тогда нужно так:

```js
import { Header } from './components/Нeader'
```

Либо сделать так:

```js
export default function Header() {}

import Header from './components/Нeader'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Примите ответ, если проблема решена.